# Visual Source Safe (VSS) help required

Tags: visual-sourcesafe

I just installed Visual SourceSave (VSS) and need some help. Please take a look at the screenshot. Is this VSS server or client? I assume this is server. So I need client which I will install on other PCs which will access this server? Or this is server/client both and I just need to install this on all machines?

[image: Screenshot: Visual SourceSafe Explorer]

And please guide me to some nice VSS tutorial.

Thanks

Comment: VSS has no server, just all clients operating on the same network share. Since network shares were never designed to operate the equivalent of a database, you sooner or later get all kinds of corruption problems. Try using Team Foundation Server or some other source control system that has a real server in its design (Exception: You work alone and want to use VSS just to store a history of your files. It's OK for that. Not fine, but OK).

Comment: So if I have got it right, I just need to share my project folder on network which every client will add in their VSS and then they checkin and checkout!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Client en server are the same tool.

[On Wikipedia there is a VSS page with links to interesting articles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_SourceSafe)

VSS is a bit dated, you might also want to checkout Subversion or if you've got some money to burn try TeamFoundationServer.

Comment: So if I have got it right, I just need to share my project folder on network which every client will add in their VSS and then they checkin and checkout!?

Comment: That is correct. You must create the users in the SourceSafe Administration tool.

Answer (score 1):

That is a shot of the client program that you use to access the repository (outside of any VS integration, we used the same thing with an old FoxPro app).  See here for details of the client...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181051(v=vs.80).aspx